# The intro-to-QM books question: reopen?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, resource-recommendation, reopen, specific-question

We have several questions asking for recommendations of books for beginner-level quantum mechanics. Many of them are closed as duplicates of this one: 
[What is a good introductory book on quantum mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33215/what-is-a-good-introductory-book-on-quantum-mechanics). It is our canonical such question and it just earned its asker a [Famous Question badge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/37/famous-question?userid=10970), so it's been seen 10k times over a year and a half and will continue to accumulate them. It is also in line with our new resource recommendation policy. However, it is still closed.

#### Should it be reopened?

I've already voted to reopen at some point, so I can't put it into the queue. How about we show this question some community love?

Comment: It does appear that it should be reopened; I have made my vote.

Comment: And like all list questions, it (1) consists 99% of people recommending the one and only thing they ever tried, with no facts or comparisons to back up their erroneous claims, and (2) has attracted a hoard of people best left to Quora, so we get things like [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/48409) pseudoscience recommendation.

Comment: @ChrisWhite: So, it gets a bad answer, and therefore thhe question must be bad?!

Comment: @Chris well answers which aren't in line with the new book policy could probably be deleted.

Comment: Why is the question STILL not reopend, what is the problem? Why can not a moderator at his 5th reopen vote to t

Comment: The 4 community reopen votes? Why is it so much easier and very common that questions get closed by 4 community members + a mod but reopen almost never happens in thes way?

Comment: @Dilaton I agree with David Z that it would be preferable to have a community reopening than a mod action. In particular, there are [a couple of Leave Closed votes](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/history), though I would be interested in hearing from their casters as to why they think that.

Comment: (That said, if a mod feels this should be reopened, they can now add their vote without it being a unilateral mod action.)

Comment: @Dilaton Mods aren't around all the time, and we're certainly not omnipresent (I had sort of expected it to have been reopened by not by the community). I reopened it; instead of making a big fuss about it you could have calmly pinged one of us in chat or something. Less politics, more doing. Also, [the leave closed votes](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/31300) are an issue, though not as much since there are 4 reopen votes+consensus on meta.

Comment: Of course it's harder for a post to get reopened. 5 people and/or a mod thought it was closeable. Usually, that means that something is wrong with it policy-wise, even if it isn't really closeable. What you say -- that questions are easily closed but hard to reopen -- just indicates that not many questions are being incorrectly closed.

Answer (score 12):

Yeah, I think that makes sense. The question in its current form seems like just the kind of thing the new recommendation policy is designed to encourage, and we should definitely have one open question about intro QM books. (Of course we also have to make sure the answers are in shape, but that can happen whenever.)

Since this is an active meta discussion I won't unilaterally reopen it just yet. I think the community can take care of that.